# VBA/excel Date comparison from text box

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I need to be able to enter a date range in two textboxes (‘txtDateFrom’ and ‘txtDateTo’) on a VBA form (I’ve already created the VBA form in Excel).  I then need to select individual rows from Sheet1 (see screenshot of Sheet1) based on column B and the date criteria from my two textboxes.

I intend using  the ‘click’ event of a button on my VBA form (cmdExtractData) to run the code.  I would then like to put this extracted data into Sheet2 of my spreadsheet so I can do further analysis on it.  Sheet2 will therefore look exactly like Sheet1, but with only those rows of data that match the date criteria selected.

I’m comfortable doing all the necessary error checking (making sure the dates are valid etc).

Spreadsheet Data:

```
1,19/07/2015,1,F,P,White Goods,One Off,£250.00
2,24/08/2015,2,D,A,Handyman Services,Ongoing,£500.00
3,21/07/2015,3,W,L,Home Assistance,One Off,£750.00
4,01/09/2015,4,F,C,Convalescent/Respite,One Off,£250.00
5,17/06/2015,5,D,H,Living Expenses,Ongoing,£500.00
6,29/11/2015,1,F,O,Specialist Equipment,One Off,£250.00
7,12/12/2015,4,D,O,Convalescent/Respite,One Off,£250.00
8,23/01/2016,2,D,L,Transport Costs,One Off,£500.00
9,27/02/2016,4,W,L,Living Expenses,One Off,£500.00
10,03/11/2015,4,F,C,Convalescent/Respite,One Off,£750.00
```

---

OK, after much fiddling I have the basis of something that works...

```
' Clear Sheet2 ready for new data
Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents

' First find the last row in the spreadsheet that has data in it.
LastRowFrom = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Loop for each entry in column B
For i = 2 To LastRowFrom
  'get the next date from column B
   TempDate = Range("B" & i).Value

   If TempDate >= txtDateFrom.Text And TempDate <= txtDateTo.Text Then
   ' Write code here if the date is in the selected range
    Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy
    Sheet2.Range("A" & i).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
    Sheet1.Select
  End If
Next i
```

This works but I can't help feeling that this is too simple.  Should I be checking for anything whilst this code is executing.  Are there any loose ends I need to tie up etc?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is not a code for me site. If you have code that is not working please post it in you original post with an explanation of what is not working. We can help with specific problems.

Comment: Have you tried to make an if statement (if date < date_to and date > date_from) inside a loop covering all rows?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Scott.  Apologies if i've already fallen foul of the rules.  The problem is I didn't really know where to start on this one, I was just becoming more and more frustrated.  Leave it with me and i'll try again...

Comment: look into using an advanced filter, it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  i'll be back when I have some code to show ;-)

Comment: OK, so I have the basis of something that works...

Comment: Good work! It looks like you solved your own problem. Oftentimes in VBA, simple is good. Since you solved your own problem, you can actually take your edit and post it as an answer, marking it as correct. This will mark the question as solved, as well as help future people who may stumble across the post. Welcome again to the community!

Answer (score 0):

First off, VBA is very EN-US-centric. Your DMY dates are going to cause confusion unless treated as their underlying raw numerical value. By using the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx), you are comparing strings-that-look-like-dates to actual dates in the cells. If the dates in the cells (column B starting with `19/07/2015`) are really strings then even a string-to-string comparison is not going to produce reliable results; e.g. `"15/04/2015"` is **not** less than `"11/03/2016"`. Treat dates as dates and strings as strings.

```
Dim dtDateFrom As Date, dtDateTo As Date, tempDate As Date
Dim i As Long, lastRowFrom As Long

' Clear Sheet2 ready for new data
Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents

' provide a parent worksheet
With Sheet1
    dtDateFrom = .Range("z1").Value
    dtDateTo = .Range("z2").Value
   'need to get real dates from your text boxes possibly like this
    'dtDateFrom = DateSerial(Split(txtDateFrom, Chr(47))(2), _
                             Split(txtDateFrom, Chr(47))(1), _
                             Split(txtDateFrom, Chr(47))(0))
    'dtDateTo = DateSerial(Split(txtDateTo, Chr(47))(2), _
                           Split(txtDateTo, Chr(47))(1), _
                           Split(txtDateTo, Chr(47))(0))

    ' First find the last row in the spreadsheet that has data in it.
    lastRowFrom = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop for each entry in column B
    For i = 2 To lastRowFrom
        'get the next date from column B
        tempDate = Range("B" & i).Value

        If tempDate >= dtDateFrom And tempDate <= dtDateTo Then
            ' simple copy with destination
            .Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy _
                Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A" & i).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

The above treats dates as dates. If they are actually strings on the worksheet, a parsing routine would be necessary to extract the correct value from the string(s).

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Thanks everyone who helped me, it was invaluable and I couldn't have got there without the hints and tips you so kindly provided.  Here is the code I ended up with (which works fine).  However, if anyone sees any glaring errors or has any suggestions for improvement please let me know.

```
' Clear Sheet2 ready for new data

Sheet2.Cells.ClearContents

' provide a parent worksheet

With Sheet1
dtDateFrom = .Range("z1").Value
dtDateTo = .Range("z2").Value

  'Get real dates from text boxes
dtDateFrom = DateSerial(Split(txtDateFrom, VBA.Chr(47))(2), _
Split(txtDateFrom, VBA.Chr(47))(1), _
Split(txtDateFrom, VBA.Chr(47))(0))
dtDateTo = DateSerial(Split(txtDateTo, VBA.Chr(47))(2), _
Split(txtDateTo, VBA.Chr(47))(1), _
Split(txtDateTo, VBA.Chr(47))(0))

' First find the last row in the spreadsheet that has data in it.
lastRowFrom = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Loop for each entry in column B
For i = 2 To lastRowFrom
    'get the next date from column B
    tempDate = Range("B" & i).Value

        ' This code searches Sheet1 for matching Dates and Selected Area
    If tempDate >= dtDateFrom And tempDate <= dtDateTo And SelectedArea = 0 Then
            Sheet1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A" & i).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        ElseIf tempDate >= dtDateFrom And tempDate <= dtDateTo And SelectedArea = 1 Then
            Sheet1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A" & i).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                Sheet2.Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1"
        ElseIf tempDate >= dtDateFrom And tempDate <= dtDateTo And SelectedArea = 2 Then
            Sheet1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A" & i).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                Sheet2.Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="2"
        ElseIf tempDate >= dtDateFrom And tempDate <= dtDateTo And SelectedArea = 3 Then
            Sheet1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A" & i).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                Sheet2.Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="3"
        ElseIf tempDate >= dtDateFrom And tempDate <= dtDateTo And SelectedArea = 4 Then
            Sheet1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A" & i).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                Sheet2.Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="4"
        ElseIf tempDate >= dtDateFrom And tempDate <= dtDateTo And SelectedArea = 5 Then
            Sheet1.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A" & i).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                Sheet2.Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="5"
    End If
Next i
End With
```